# E12 led smart bulbs don't work in ceiling fan

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan, led

I tried replacing two e12 bulbs with led e12 smart bulbs but with both leds the lights don't turn on with the wall switch or smart phone.

Here's the weird part. If I put one incandescent bulb in together with an led smart bulb then the led will work with the switch and smart phone.

I realize I can't mix these bulbs, but does anyone have an explanation for why the leds wont work together in the fan?

Comment: O.o what make and model are these bulbs?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem.  It's due to some sort of "powered switch" (i.e. a switch that's more than a switch) powering itself by leaking power through the bulbs. Works great on incandescents because an unlit incandescent is nearly a dead short. For LEDs it just makes them go crazy.

Anyway, the cure is to either a) leave one incandescent in, or b) wire in a paralleled device such as a Lutron LUT-MLC which emulates the incandescent light effect.